# SQL create new columns based on product classification and client buying the product

Tags: sql

I have a table with clients and a table of products each client is buying

To retrive each client interest in any product I wrote the following SQL statement

```
SELECT 
t1.ClientID
,t2.ProductID
  FROM [DTBA].[dbo].[Client] t1
  inner join [DTBA].[dbo].[Product] t2 on t2.ClientID = t1.ClientID
```

This will return me a full list of client and product they are buying as per below

| Client ID | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 100017 | 7000 |
| 100018 | 7001 |
| 100019 | 7000 |
| 100021 | 7002 |
| 100024 | 7001 |
| 100025 | 7001 |
| 100028 | 7003 |

What I would like to do is to create a SQL query that will return me the clientID and a column for each productID with result of a binary file if the client is buying a product or not as per the example below

| ClientID | ProductID | 7000 | 7001 | 7002 | 7003 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100017 | 7000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 100018 | 7001 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100019 | 7000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 100021 | 7002 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 100024 | 7001 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100025 | 7001 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100028 | 7003 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I would appreciate any help as to define each cols and retrive the binary info cols

Comment: Did try to paste a text but was going all over the place. I do not need to create a new Table it would be enough for me a select statement. I did not link to any external site, the images is a copy paste from my xls to what I'd like to achieve.

I do apologize if this is not convenient for you, but I rather seek an answer if possible, if not, thanks anyhow

Comment: @stickybit thanks for your comments, I tried to put the question using a formatting I did not see before. Please let me know if this is what you were looking for and thanks again if you can provide any help.
Really not interested in vote for a question but rather in finding a solution but, if a vote is expression of data not provided correctly then I have some problems to understand how everything works...if I was an IT person would not have been here and I guess this is clear from my very basic question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to answer your question is going to be with a whole bunch of case statements. Something like this:

```
SELECT
ClientID,
ProductID,
SUM( CASE WHEN ProductID = 7000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 7000, 
SUM( CASE WHEN ProductID = 7001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 7001,
SUM( CASE WHEN ProductID = 7002 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 7002,
SUM( CASE WHEN ProductID = 7003 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 7003
  FROM [DTBA].[dbo].[Client] t1
  inner join [DTBA].[dbo].[Product] t2 on t2.ClientID = t1.ClientID
  GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate. I was doing that in a vlookup way in xls and had no idea how to do it in SQL. Really thanks, really appreciate. I'll give it a go and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, let me know if it works. If it does, could you accept my solution. Thanks

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help! I wish you a lovely day! Just accepted your solution!